# slider inside tabs, need to set slick position when toggle in

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have jquery slick slider inside tabs and the slider wont calculate the layout until the tab is active.

Here is the current slick code.

```
// JavaScript Document


jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {


  jQuery(".slider").slick({ asNavFor: '.slider',
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  responsive: [
         {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
  ]

  });
 jQuery(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        $('.panel-collapse first-toggle collapse in').get(0).slick.setPosition();         
  });
});
```

and here is the html output page [my html output page](http://demo.armentum.co/thatsinsurance/compare-travel-insurance-fav/?cn=4079%2C4098%2C3863%2C3869)

If you click on the tab labelled Optional Cover, the slick is squashed over on one side.

I looked on Ken Wheelers reddit for the slider and his comments were

> This is because when a carousel is hidden, slick can't properly calculate its dimensions.
>
> An easy way to fix is to go into your bootstrap css and use
>   max-height: 0px and max-height: auto instead of display: none and
>   display: block.
>
> Another way, is when a tab is shown, call
>   $('.the-carousel-thats-getting-shown').get(0).slick.setPosition()

I tried changing the css outside of bootstrap with !important for the class but max-height:auto is coming up invalid markup and it didnt fix it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`Change` event only for form elements (input, textarea or select).You need to bind a function to the `DOMSubtreeModified` mutation event.

Example:

```
  $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    $('.panel-collapse.collapse.first-toggle.in').get(0).slick.setPosition();         
  });
```

Comment: I have put it in, but am getting a type error $ is not a function?

Comment: Are you loading the right slick.js file? Are you loading the right jQuery file? Have you included jQuery before slick.js?@DeniseField

Comment: also on the classes these are multiple classes do I need to separate each one like this ( '.panel-collapse','.collapse','.first-toggle','.in')   or in fact its only the '.in' that changes from the line of classes, so is that the only one that needs to be included?

Comment: no its after, but I am not100% its right as no expert the js is here [link]http://www.thatsinsurance.online/slider/slick/slickthats.js[/link] my original classes were in different order so I corrected those.  I am trying to solve a problem on slick here [link]http://demo.armentum.co/thatsinsurance/compare-travel-insurance-fav/?cn=4079%2C4098%2C3863%2C3869[/link] where if the tabs are started closed slick doesnt set the layout.  The person who made slick replied to another persons query to put this code in, but I have absolutely no idea how to correctly do this

Comment: add this after including jQuery. and can you show me your full html and jS?and i update my answer. @DeniseField

Comment: thanks @Ashiquzzaman for your help on this, been working on it all day and I am just not knowledgable enough to sort it.. very frustrating.

Comment: Never be frustrated. This is the symbol of a good Developer.@DeniseField

Comment: I have now changed to where I am at with this, also included what the author of slick slider suggested. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance